# How do prevent the browser from sending the Authorization header to the new location when following a redirect, using Node.js/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am building a backend using node.js
I want to redirect a signed user request to a signed URL on AWS S3.
The problem is that when I use `response.redirect(<file url>)` The browser is sending the authorization header with the redirect request and AWS rejects it.
How do I strip the response header of the authorization?

This is the code I am using

```
const signedUrl = await FilesService.generateSignedUrl(); //this works fine
res.redirect(signedUrl);
```

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the nature of the issue you are reporting. Please advise if I have made an error.  This question is interesting, because the browser should never do that.  Which browsers have you tested with?

Comment: It is not the browser. It is the backend. I tried it on chrome. This is actually the expected behaviour according to the documentation but i am trying to go around it

Comment: What is the expected behavior, and according to *which* documentation?  The back-end does not send an Authorization header.  That's a request header.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove the headers before the redirect.

```
        res.removeHeader('Authorization');
```